# What are the solutions to the following equation (which may or may not be a differential equation)?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, convex-analysis

Let $X = \mathbb{R}^n$ and let $T\colon X\to X$. Suppose for every $x\in X$,
$$x - T(x) = \nabla\tfrac{1}{2}\|x-T(x)\|^2.$$
What are all the solutions to this equation? I am aware the (generally *nonsmooth*) projections onto nonempty closed convex subsets of $X$ will satisfy this but are there other solutions out there?

Comment: $Tx=x$ is obvious one. For the other ones setting $u=x-Tx$ may provide little information. In this case you'll have a first order system of coupled quasilinear equations: $2u_i=\frac{\partial}{\partial _i}\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^nu_j^2$  for $i,\,j=1..n$.

Comment: $f = \| x - T(x) \|$ satisfies the Eikonal equation $\|\nabla f\| = 1$ wherever $f > 0,$ so it should be something like a distance function. If we actually knew it was the distance to some convex $\Omega$ then we could immediately conclude that $T$ is the nearest-point projection to $\Omega$, but I don't know any such global characterization of Eikonal solutions.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis do you happen to know that the solution (as in the case of distance functions) of Eikonal equation is unique or not? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @weirdo: I'm not too familiar with the equation, sorry. I expect the solution should be unique if you impose strong enough boundary conditions.

Comment: @weirdo: Hi, can you add a link to the question you asked about the Eikonal equation that is directly related to this? Thanks.